# Pointers in structures pointing to another structure

Tags: c

Imagine two structures defined as:

```
struct list
{
  struct block *first;
  struct block *last;
};

struct block
{
  uint8_t *address;
  uint32_t alloc_count;
  struct block *prev;
  struct block *next;
};
```

In case I do list->first->address, would it work? Since list->first points to the block structure which has an address value. What about list->first->next (since that also points to the block structure?).
And what if I do block->first, I assume that wouldn't work since first is defined in the list-structure?

In case I define a new structure and declare it like: struct block *temporary = list->first, would temporary be a list of blocks, or just the first block of list?

These questions might sound stupid, but I've been reading about structures for the past two hours and can't seem to get around this. If anyone could clarify, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What happened when you tried? How did you try? Please show the code you tried and report the errors you got or the behaviour you observed.

Comment: There's no way to test this for me since I've been struggling actually assigning values to elements of the structures :/

Comment: You want to know how to allocate data to this doubly linked list? And what this `uint8_t *address;`
  `uint32_t alloc_count;` properties stands for?

Comment: You have been struggling. Show how. Explain how it failed. That will be helpful, by demonstrating your level of knowledge and understanding and by illustrating your way of thinking.

Comment: Draw a picture/diagram to visualize, with arrows representing (non-null) pointers. That helps immensely for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything of that you wrote because it's just a declaration of structs, not real objects you're dealing with. But if you create some, you could perform all of actions you'd like to.

```
struct list new_list;
struct block new_block;

uint8_t address = new_list->first->address; // OK
struct block target_block = new_list->first->next; // OK
```

Of course, you can't do `new_block->first` because you don't have `first` field in your block structure.

`struct block *temporary = list->first` will be not a list of blocks nor the first block of list, it'll be a pointer to the first block of list. But you can easily access all the list through `first->next`, `first->next->next`, etc. Just put `i = i->next` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Note that since the code is written in C, there is no type `list`in the fragments in the question. There is only a type `struct list`.  C++ does it differently

Comment: Oh, really, thanks, totally forgot about that. Don't deal with C for two years though. Edited it.